# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on Object.getBytes() method while downloading > 90MB files

Tags: java, arrays, file, download, java-io

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)`
```

Trying to download file greater than 90MB. I'm getting exception when calling `Object.getBytes()`.
Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: The file goes from where to where ?

Comment: Can you please add more details? source code, config files etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
InputStream inputStream = object.getStream(); , resolves this issue.Im able to download 2GB files as well.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read a 90mb file into a JVM that is only 64mb by default.  You can change the memory settings from the command line:

`-Xms128m -Xmx256m`

This will set the initial size of the JVM to 128mb and the maximum size to 256mb.  You can of course change them to suit your needs.